# Problem with DateTime.ParseExact in Azure Functions for September and Australia CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I am trying to parse a string to `DateTime` in an Azure Function running on Windows with an isolated worker process on .NET Core v7.

This is the code:

```
var date = "4 Sep 2023";
var valParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, new[] { "d MMM yyyy" }, new CultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This is failing with:

> String '4 Sep 2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

The code runs on my machine and parses the date correctly.

I am lost as to why this would not run on the function.

This is a sample function I setup to demonstrate the issue:

```
    [Function(FunctionName)]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger(cronEveryFiveMinutes)] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var date = "4 Sep 2023";

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, new[] { "d MMM yyyy" }, new CultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var rithparse))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Parsed Date: {rithparse}");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to parse the date: {date}");
        }
    }
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: I can clearly see, you are not using my code, You need to use       this,       ```if (DateTime.TryParseExact(rithdate, new[] { "d MMM yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var rithparse))``` and not this ```new CultureInfo("en-AU"),```

Comment: The problem is with CultureInfo("en-AU"), donot use it

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4mdXbr Can you check if the CultureInfo instance has been constructed correctly in the Azure Function?

Comment: ^^ Oddly, it even works in fiddle if I pass `null` ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rd6T9A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst RithwikBojja's answer provides a solution, it does not explain why this is happening with `CultureInfo("en-AU")`.

There was a change to the en-AU culture which raised this issue, see:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87307
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86643

This change saw the months June, July, and September change the output to `June`, `July`, and `Sept` for the `MMM` format. Which lead to the discrepancy as in my local development environment it was still `Jun` `Jul` and `Sep`.

The change is due to the switch to [ICU datasources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

The fix to our issue, since we want to prevent changes to globalisation cultures to break the parsing logic, is to use `InvariantCulture` as suggested in RithwikBojja's answer .

Comment: Yes @Luis its a bug that the code only works with InvariantCulture, That is why i gave an example answer with InvariantCulture

Answer (score 1):

> Problem with DateTime ParseExact In Azure Functions

You can use below code to parse date:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace FunctionApp96
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var rithdate = "7 Dec 2023";
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(rithdate, new[] { "d MMM yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var rithparse))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik, Parsed Date: {rithparse}");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Hello Rithwik,Failed to parse the date: {rithdate}");
            }
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Check my update, it does not work

Comment: If you use my code correctly you will get output as i have got, Use this code:
```DateTime.TryParseExact(rithdate, new[] { "d MMM yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var rithparse```

Comment: @SPT OP explicitly stated that it did _not_ ...